# Pitch Detection for Music

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a rhythm based music game within which you should (theoretically) be able to choose any song you would like. This is being created in Unity(5.4.1) with C#.

In real time the pitch of the song it detected and shown to the user through visualizers.

The issue I'm having is I have created a visualizer but this barely shows the higher pitch notes. I fear this is because (as with most music)  a number of pitches are played at once (for the sake of testing I was using Darude Sandstorm while waiting for sound guy to give me the music). Eventually, I want this pitch detection to tell the user whether to hit a high, medium or low note.

I've tried using 
    `GetComponent<FFT>().PitchValue;`
and
   `AudioListener.GetSpectrumData(2048, 0, FFTWindow.Hamming);`

I guess the fear is that it just can't be done on songs with a number of pitches being played at once (ie base overriding the high pitch).

I'd love to hear any advice or know if anyone has overcome a similar problem.

This is an example of what I'm working with right now, I've tried a number of different online solutions (some of the information is actually from a tutorial linked in the code commented) which I intend to fully reference if I continue on this path (I've been working on this part time for a couple of weeks now). It makes a pretty visualiser but I can't seem to utilize it fully. This works well as a visualiser without the if else statements, this is just where I am doing some trial and error at the moment. I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELLANEFw5B8)

```
//the class{
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    public class soundspectrume : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject prefab; // the cube prefab
    public int numberOfObjects = 25; // number of cubes to make visualizer
    public float radius = 5f; // radius of circle
    public GameObject[] cubes; //array of the created cubes
    public float PitchValue;
    public Color mycolour;

    void Start() 
    {
        PitchValue = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<FFT>().PitchValue;//this declares the pitch value but it will always be 0 as it is declared before the musics intro on start
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++) //loop to create the cubes 
        {
            float angle = i * Mathf.PI * 2 / numberOfObjects;
            Vector3 pos = new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angle), 0, Mathf.Sin(angle)) * radius; // this code is from unity docs https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html
            Instantiate(prefab, pos, Quaternion.identity); //instanciate's cubes 
        }
        cubes = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("cube");
    }

// Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        PitchValue = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<FFT>().PitchValue;
        print(PitchValue); 
        float[] spectrum = AudioListener.GetSpectrumData(2048, 0, FFTWindow.Hamming); // always move sample to power of 2, max will make cubes move without punch lower numbers less control.
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
        {
            if (PitchValue <= 200)
            {
                Vector3 previousscale = cubes[i].transform.localScale;
                previousscale.y = spectrum[i] * 500; //take spectrum number and multiply, higher frequency songs will need greater multiplier
                cubes[i].transform.localScale = previousscale;
            }
            else if (PitchValue >= 201)
            {
                Vector3 previousscale = cubes[i].transform.localScale;
                previousscale.y = spectrum[i] * 1; //take spectrum number and multiply, higher frequency songs will need greater multiplier
                cubes[i].transform.localScale = previousscale;
            }
            else if (PitchValue >= 500)
            {
                Vector3 previousscale = cubes[i].transform.localScale;
                previousscale.y = spectrum[i] * 100; //take spectrum number and multiply, higher frequency songs will need greater multiplier
                cubes[i].transform.localScale = previousscale;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Attached image with some of the pitch output values printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JR5NW.png)

Thanks for commenting so far, sorry I didn't attach this at the start

Comment: What are you using for your sound pickup?  The average laptop does not have great microphones built into them.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I believe they are using an mp3 or similar file format, and then getting the spectrum data of the `AudioSource`, using the `AudioListener` as an intermediate

Comment: @RBarryYoungI am indeed using an MP3. I set the pitch data to print on update and it does seem to be returning a range of values (0-654.000)

Comment: @SamanthaRoach by the way can we see an actual code example in case there's something easy to fix?

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre I attached the code as an answer (can't edit my post from earlier) hopefuly you can understand what I'm struggling with. Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: No, I'm not asking about the data format, I am asking about your audio hardware.  Are you using the mic built into your laptop/PC or are you using an external and/or professional mic?

Comment: @RBarryYoung ... I am saying there is no microphone involved

Comment: @SamanthaRoach Delete the answer, I'll edit it in for you!

Comment: Ah, I see. OK, sorry.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Sorry for any confusion the sound is within the game already, there doesn't need to be a mic. Unfortunately, I can't seem to delete the answer - thanks for updating the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone out there is working on something similar, I managed to seperate the pitches as they came using an array to access the FFT spectrum data.

All feedback welcome.

I found this by learning how FFT works (seriously recommend the khan academy on it) and by finding this awesome guys video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_8JSWVT36k in which he does the same thing in JS.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SPECTRUMANALYZER : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Update( )
    {
        float[] spectrum = new float[1024];
        AudioListener.GetSpectrumData(spectrum, 0, FFTWindow.Rectangular );
        float l1 = spectrum [0] + spectrum [2] + spectrum [4];
        float l2 = spectrum [10] + spectrum [11] + spectrum [12];
        float l3 = spectrum[20] + spectrum [21] + spectrum [22];
        float l4 = spectrum [40] + spectrum [41] + spectrum [42] + spectrum [43];
        float l5 = spectrum [80] + spectrum [81] + spectrum [82] + spectrum [83];
        float l6 = spectrum [160] + spectrum [161] + spectrum [162] + spectrum [163];
        float l7 = spectrum [320] + spectrum [321] + spectrum [322] + spectrum [323];
        Debug.Log(l7);
        GameObject [] cubes = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("CUBE");

    for( int i = 1; i < cubes.Length; i++ )
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 1:
                cubes[i].gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, l1 * 100, 0.5f); // base drum
                break;
            case 2:
                cubes[i].gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, l2 * 200, 0.5f); // base guitar
                break;
            case 3:
                cubes[i].gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, l3 * 400, 0.5f);
                break;
            case 4:
                cubes[i].gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, l4 * 800, 0.5f);
                break;
            case 5:
                cubes[i].gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, l5 * 1600, 0.5f);
                break;
            case 6:
                cubes[i].gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, l6 * 3200, 0.5f);
                break;
            case 7:
                cubes[i].gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, l7 * 6400, 0.5f); //*tsk tsk tsk
                break;
        }           
    }
}
```

}